# Coefficient of Determination relationship

Tags: statistics, regression

$R^2 = \frac{SSREG}{SSTOT}$ or $R^2 = 1-\frac{SSRES}{SSTOT}$

If $X$ is the predictor random variable for science SAT

and $Y$ is the predictor random variable science GPA

given by equation $$\hat Y = -1 + 0.006X$$

and $R^2 = 0.3$

what do we say the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ is in this case?

Comment: $R^2$ cannot equal $3$. It is one minus a manifestly positive quantity, so always $\le 1.$ (It will be between zero and one provided the fit is done by least squares and there is a constant term.) As to the question, it is vague... what are the “options”?

Comment: $0.3$ sorry. And what do you mean by options?

Comment: I mean that I don’t know what specifically the question “what is the relationship between $X$ and $Y$?” is asking. Usually this kind of question implies there are some list of options, like e.g. “positively correlated” and “negatively correlated”

Comment: Not sure. All that was given is the fitted regression line and asking what does the coefficient of determination say about the relationship of X and Y. Like Should researchers use science SAT scores (X) to track performance for students in science (Y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Science SAT accounts for about $30\%$ of the variation of the GPA